# Multi-lang feature in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, render, google-translate, google-translation-api

> I created a web app which have events that are dynamically showing when admin/user are uploading the data.

I want to add language feature into my web app.

By reading all articles i see i have to create JSON files for each different language.  But this would be only good for hard-coded items (like headers).

How can/should I deal with "unknown text" which is entered / uploaded ad-hoc.
How Would I go about this problem

TECHNOLOGIES: ANGULAR 7 .Net core API

Comment: You can try using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).  It will allow you to load translations dynamically and not force you to recompile the project. The basic tutorial uses `json` files, but since it uses a link, you can direct it to a web API.

Comment: Please clarify:  is you aim to auto-translate through google API's?   Or is it just the aim, to be able to make/use dynamic translations which aren't known upfront (without the use of google API's)

Comment: @jcuypers I want to add a dropdown , which can have different language . So when i select my text changes. I can buy google transalte api too. 
Please Help

Comment: @Oram  But in ngx-translate . I have to make different .json files to different languages .

Comment: @AnshulRawat  I just wanted to be clear about the tags/categories you have chosen for you question.  I think your question is quite broad.  its not only about having/or not have to specify translation tags / json  but also where these translations would be placed etc.   you need to be more specific, since what you want can be anything like a user being able to upload product description in different languages and/or be able to describe dynamic forms for multiple languages.  its not just a button "switch language".

Comment: I think it would be a good start for you to describe, in detail, one very specific use-case/requirement (screen / action / interaction... ) where you couldn't use a standard library like ngx-translate, i18n, i10n, ... and to show what you have tried to do and what the exact outcome needs to be.

Comment: @AnshulRawat As I said, in ngx-translate you can refer to a web API that returns json - you don't have to have a pre-made json file. If the user uploads new data, the response from this API can take the new data into account without the need of recompiling the application.

Comment: @Oram But i am only taking English language from users . Like there info , address and then displaying them using API . 
But my reading all articles i see they have different language json too , which i dont have any.

Comment: You have two separate problems: 1. You get the input from the user and translate it. This can be done with the [google translation api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/). You do this once for the input and save the result. 2. You need to get the translations from the server dynamically. You can do it with something like ngx-translate as described above.

Answer (score 0):

you could write your own custom loader to do whatever you like.  what you refer to is most probably the standard httploader with json.  If you look at the source code of the ngx-translate you will see it does nothing:  (if you check the code of httploader it will load json files from a server etc).  you create your own custom code to do whatever you like.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";

export abstract class TranslateLoader {
  abstract getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any>;
}

/**
 * This loader is just a placeholder that does nothing, in case you don't need a loader at all
 */
@Injectable()
export class TranslateFakeLoader extends TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of({});
  }
}
```